# same keys values array to be formed key values array

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have an array with same keys as and different values  ny i need to make new array with all different values of same key to be as one array for that particular key (check the bold keys)

```
[

    {
        0002044175: {
            "image_org": "",
            "image_id": "8279",

        }
    },
    {
       0002044175: {
            "image_org": "",
            "image_id": "13295050",

        }
    },
    {
        0002047777: {
            "image_org": "",
            "image_id": "13295051",

        }
    }
]
```

my result array to be

```
[
"result":
{
    {
        0002044175:
          {
             {
            "image_org": "",
            "image_id": "8279",

            }
            {
            "image_org": "",
            "image_id": "13295050",

            }
       }
    },

    {
        0002047777:
          { 
            {
            "image_org": "",
            "image_id": "13295051",

            }
          }
    }

}
```

]

Comment: format the code and make your question clear... so that we can help you out

Comment: The result you say you want isn't valid JSON. What's the question / problem?

Comment: Is there any question?

Comment: i have cleared my question if yet clarification needed kindly let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loop through the array and index to be as the ids then same ids will be one of the node in array